# RuntimeException - AppCompat does not support the current theme features

Tags: android

Whenever I run the app on my device it does not open.

```
01-15 18:55:18.264 4285-4285/com.example.adeel.lfc_news E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.adeel.lfc_news, PID: 4285
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.adeel.lfc_news/com.example.adeel.lfc_news.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features: { windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false, android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false, windowNoTitle: false }
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:458)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                          at com.example.adeel.lfc_news.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

MainActivity Code

```
package com.example.adeel.lfc_news;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

import com.example.adeel.lfc_news.Fragments.CardContentFragment;
import com.example.adeel.lfc_news.Fragments.ListContentFragment;
import com.example.adeel.lfc_news.Fragments.TileContentFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Adding Toolbar to Main screen
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Setting ViewPager for each Tabs
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        // Set Tabs inside Toolbar
        TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    // Add Fragments to Tabs
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ListContentFragment(), "List");
        adapter.addFragment(new TileContentFragment(), "Tile");
        adapter.addFragment(new CardContentFragment(), "Card");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: seems it has problem with your theme, share your code.

Comment: @shahzainali code added any more you need?

Comment: I think this has to do with How you define or are using ActionBar. I think you should have `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;` as an import and then when getting the ActionBar use `youractionbar = getSupportActionBar();` and then use available methods. However, you should really post your code.

Comment: Please show the theme definition for the Activity (usually in `styles.xml`)

Comment: @SG81 also share your styles.xml.

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant part of your error:

> AppCompat does not support the current theme features: {
>   windowActionBar: false, windowActionBarOverlay: false,
>   android:windowIsFloating: false, windowActionModeOverlay: false,
>   windowNoTitle: false }

Either make sure your app does not use those features or enable the features.